# Read value from HTML form into Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms

Sorry if the formatting is wrong.

Basically, I am trying to read the values of the HSV forms, populated by JavaScript, in Python.

Basically, the user selects a location on a color wheel, and the HSV value of this location populates the HSV forms below. I am trying to access these values in Python, but because these forms are "dynamically populated", I'm not having any luck. Any suggestions on how to access these values in Python would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Getting colors </title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="jscolor.js"></script>
<input class="jscolor {onFineChange:'update(this)'}" value="ffcc00">

<form>
    H:<br>
        <input id="p1" type="text" name="H"><br>
    S:<br>
        <input id="p2" type="text" name="S"><br>
    V:<br>
        <input id="p3" type="text" name="V"><br>
</form>

<script>
function update(picker) {
    document.getElementById("p1").value = Math.round(picker.hsv[0]) ;
    document.getElementById("p2").value = Math.round(picker.hsv[1]) ;
    document.getElementById("p3").value = Math.round(picker.hsv[2]) ;
}
</script>

<img src="https://192.168.1.24:5050/cam.mjpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try `selenium` http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/